# Getting InvalidURIError on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run bundle install I get this error, I am using ruby 1.9.3p429

[`initialize': the scheme http does not accept registry part: manish:password@mani.mylabs.com:4228;
    (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError) ]

I have searched on StackOverflow for similar issue, but the current solutions posted on earlier posts don't solve my error. Any idea or solution is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: can you include your gemfile?

Comment: No, I can't include any gem in Gemfile.